# Animating a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently, when my app transitions from one ViewController to the next using this code it pops in. How do I add an animated transition between controllers here? Do I have to add code to the inside of the view?The code below is located in my AppDelagate.

```
if checkSomething {
  // Some code 
} else {
  let LoginViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"HomeView")
  let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController)
  self.window?.rootViewController = navController
}
```

Comment: Which controllers do you want to animate between?  Generally you wouldn't transition your first view controller.

Comment: This is a transition from my first view controller to my second